# Remove sum equaling zero from Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

[Kibana 7.9.0v]

[EDIT]
[image: Country shipment amounts]

I've been trying to remove fields from a bar graph in which their sum is 0.

Currently, I am doing a sum aggregation and displaying the results on a bar graph. The sums are correct but the graph shows sums that are 0. There are documents of which the field value is 0, let's call this field `quantity` therefore `'quantity': 0` is a possibility. I just want to see sums >= 1. I know I can do this if I add a filter where `'quantity' is not 0` but I know that Kibana used to ignore these zero sums before.

I've tried adding `{"min_doc_count": 1}` to the JSON input portion of both the Metrics & Buckets sections but an error is brought up. I've also looked into the advanced settings but have found no section for setting the minimum.

Comment: Got some sample docs and perhaps a few screenshots of what chart settings you've chosen?

Comment: Added image to show bar graph and values @JoeSorocin

Answer (score 0):

This'd be possible only through a [`bucket_selector` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) which'd filter the zero buckets out. Unfortunately, Kibana doesn't support it yet -- though it's a highly upvoted [feature request](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17544).

Until it becomes available, you'll need to use raw query DSL -- something along the lines of:

```
POST countries/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "sum_agg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        },
        "bucket_selector_agg": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sum_agg": "sum_agg"
            },
            "script": "params.sum_agg > 0"          <---
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and visualize it outside of Kibana.